# WooCommerce: Remove a field from the General table

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I added an input field to the "General" tab of WooCommerce using the **woocommerce_wp_text_input** hook.

However I removed the line of code as I no longer need the field, it still shows up under the "General" tab, I've cleared all cache from the server and I don't have any caching plugins on the site.

I've searched for a remove hook but it doesn't seem to exist.

Any ideas of what could be the problem will help!

Thanks